# Defining a constructor for a derived class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

Conventional wisdom is that to simulate OOP in Javascript, we do everything in terms of functions and prototypes:

```
var fooObject = function () {
  //Variables should be defined in the constructor function itself,
  //rather than the prototype so that each object will have its own variables

  this.someProperty = 5; //Default value
};

//Functions should be defined on the prototype chain so that each object does not
//have its own, separate function methods attached to it for performing the same
//tasks.

fooObject.prototype.doFoo = function () {
  //Foo
}
```

Now, to create a derived class, we do:

```
var derivedFromFoo = new foo();
```

But what happens if we want to do some other stuff in our constructor for the derived object? Like set other properties? Can we do something like

```
var derivedFromFoo = function () {
  this = new foo();
};
```

Comment: FWIW, you can never assign to `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new foo();
```

That's an instance, not a class.

To create a derived class, you need to make a new function, call the base ctor from inside of it, then set the new function's `prototype` to an object created from the base `prototype`:

```
function Derived() {
    Base.call(this);
}
Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

For more details, and a longer, more-correct implementation, see my [blog post](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/).

Comment: +1 for `call(this)` to call a "superclass" constructor